# Этимология слова "злорадство"

Tags: этимология

Заинтересовала этимология слова "злорадство". На случайных сайтах (например, https://ecanet.ru/word/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) пишут, что это калька с немецкого Schadenfreude (что выглядит разумно), но ссылок на источники нет и сам я найти их не смог, поэтому сомнения остаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этимологические словари как-то обходят это слово. Есть сведения у Г. Цыганенко, она не связывает его с калькированием, хотя вот "злополучный", "злословить" - греческие кальки.
Галина Павловна указывает, что слово "злорадство" образовано на базе сочетания *злая радость* с помощью суфф. - ств-, как "добрососедство". Похоже образуется в 19 веке "злободневный" - на базе сочетания *злоба дневи*.

В Викисловаре и Википедии содержится тот же материал, что указан у Вас. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1500363. Материал проверен, так что, вероятно, есть две точки зрения на этот вопрос. Мне ближе русская версия, злая радость - вполне понятно русскому человеку без калькирования.